# How to convert a PCRE2 regex to JavaScript?

Tags: regex

This is the PCRE2 regexp:

`(?<=hello )(?:[^_]\w++)++`

It's intended use is against strings like the following:

`Hello Bob (Marius) Smith.   -> Match "Bob"`

`Hello Bob Jr. (Joseph) White -> Match "Bob Jr."`

`Hello Bob Jr. IInd (Paul) Jobs -> Match "Bob Jr. IInd"`

You get the point.

Essentially there is a magic word, in this case "hello", followed by a first name, followed by a second name which is always between parens.
First names could be anything really. A single word, a list of words followed by punctuation, and so on. Heck, look at Elon Musks' kids' name (X Æ A-Xii) to see how weird names can get :)

Let's only assume ascii, though. Æ is not in my targets :)

I'm at a loss on how to convert this Regexp to JS, and the only viable solution I found was to use PCRE2-wasm on node which spins up a wasm virtual machine and sucks up 1gb of resources just for that. That's insane.

Comment: Javascript does not support possessive quantifiers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would match your cases in ECMAscript.

```
(?<=[Hh]ello )(?:[^_][\w.]+)+
```

You need to look for a capital H done by looking for `[Hh]` instead of `h`, as your testcases starts with a capital `H` and your + needs to be single to be used in ECMAscript.
also you need to include a `.` with the `\w` since it is included in some names.

https://regex101.com/r/lkZK7w/1

-- thanks "D M" for pointing out the missing `.` in the testcase.

Comment: I don't believe this matches case 2 or case 3. Expected `Bob Jr.` and got `Bob Jr`. Expected `Bob Jr. IINd` and got `Bob Jr`. [proof](https://regex101.com/r/z14Vk1/1/)

Comment: Actually that's a bug with the PCRE regexp as well. Seems it doesnt match the period and after the period. argh :D

Comment: @DM you are perfectly right, thanks for pointing that out. 
@DLeonardi, i have updated the answer to include `.` in the name.

Answer (score 1):

@Nils has the correct answer.

If you do need to expand your acceptable character set, you can use the following regex. [Check it out](https://regex101.com/r/WxpOfL/1). The `g`, `m`, and `i` flags are set.

```
(?<=hello ).*(?=\([^\)]*?\))
```

> ```
> Hello Bob (Marius) Smith.
> Hello Bob Jr. (Joseph) White
> Hello Bob Jr. IInd (Paul) Jobs
> Hello X Æ A-Xii (Not Elon) Musk
> Hello Bob ()) Jr. ( (Darrell) Black
> ```
>
> | Match Number | Characters | Matched Text |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | Match 1 | 6-10 | Bob |
> | Match 2 | 32-40 | Bob Jr. |
> | Match 3 | 61-74 | Bob Jr. IInd |
> | Match 4 | 92-102 | X Æ A-Xii |
> | Match 5 | 124-138 | Bob ()) Jr. ( |

The idea is pretty simple:

1. Look behind for your keyword: `(?<=hello )`.
2. Look ahead for your middle name: `(?=\([^\)]*?\))` (anything inside a set of parenthesis that is not a closing parenthesis, lazily so you don't take part of the first name).
3. Take everything between as your first name: `.*`.

Answer (score 0):

The `++` does not work as Javascript does not support possessive quantifiers.

As *a first name, followed by a second name which is always between parens*, you might also use a capture group with a match instead of a lookbehind.

```
\b[Hh]ello (\w+.*?)\s*\([^()\s]+\)
```

- `\b[Hh]ello`  Match `hello`  or `Hello`
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `\w.*?` Match 1+ word chars followed by any char as least as possible
- `)` Close group 1
- `\s*\([^()\s]*\)` Match optional whitespace char followed by `(` till `)`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/EuxKJ0/1)

```js
const regex = /\b[Hh]ello (\w+.*?)\s*\([^()\s]+\)/;
["Hello Bob (Marius) Smith.",
  "Hello Bob Jr. (Joseph) White",
  "Hello Bob Jr. IInd (Paul) Jobs"
].forEach(s => {
  const m = s.match(regex);
  if (m) {
    console.log(m[1]);
  }
})
```

With the lookbehind, you might also match word characters followed by an optionally repeated capture group matching whitspace chars followed by word characters or a dot.

```
(?<=[Hh]ello )\w+(?:\s+[\w.]+)*
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/JO8R1H/1)